# how to convert column values from a string into float while having characters in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following column [image]

I want to change it from string to float; I tried `astype(float)`. However, I think it had an error because of `""` in the values. How can I deal with these double quotes?

Comment: `column.str.strip('"').astype(float)`